# Cпавн префаба в рандомной точке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно заспавнить префаб противника в рандомной точке за областью экрана.
Как можно реализовать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject enemy1;
    public GameObject enemy2;
    public GameObject enemy3;
    public int maxe = 10; // кол-во противников максимальное
    public int stime = 1; // время между спавном объектов   
    public int counte;
    public int killse;
    public int levele = 1;
    void Update()
    {
        if(counte < 10)
        {
            Instantiate(enemy1);
            counte++;
        }
        if(counte == 0)
        {
            levele++;
        }
    }
}
```

На данный момент имею вот это. enemy1 спавнится в точке, где ранее был размещен префаб.

Comment: Сначала изучите  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html Затем https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Ну так берите enemy1.transform.position = new Vector3(координаты за пределами камеры)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float x = Random.Range(0f, 100f);
float y = Random.Range(0f, 100f);
float z = Random.Range(0f, 100f); // Если игра в 2d, то z = 1f;
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
GameObject gm = Instantiate(enemy1, pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Где **pos** - позиция объекта.

Для того, чтобы выставлять рандомно Вам надо определить в каких пределах Ваши "враги" могут спауниться.

За рандом отвечает функция Random.Range(0, 1), где 0 - минимальное значение, а 1 - максимальное

Answer (score 2):

У метода Instantiate есть перегруженный вариант, который принимает вектор с координатами спавна и кватернион для указания начального поворота объекта.
Например:

```
GameObject enemyInstance = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, new Vector3(-5, 1, 3), Quaternion.identity);
```

Настоятельно рекомендую прочесть ссылки, которые дали в комментариях.
Также координаты можно указать напрямую через компонент Transform.

Comment: А как сделать точку рандомной? Когда то делал это, но не могу вспомнить.

Comment: Метод Range класса Random в помощь